# Laravel Flash Data Persisting indefinitely

Tags: php, laravel, session

I am showing the response for a form submission using the flashdata, but it is persisting forever.

For example, when a form is validated and submitted successfully, the success message is shown and no matter how many times I refresh the page or go to other pages, it is still showing the success message.

My redirect (after validation) is as follows:

```
// Redirect back with success message
return redirect()->back()
->with('form_' . $form->identifier . '_response', json_encode([
    'status' => 'success'
]));
```

And in the view it checks like this:

```
@if(session('form_'.$form->identifier.'_response'))

        @if(json_decode(session('form_'.$form->identifier.'_response'),true)['status'] == 'success')

            <div class="alert alert-success">Form has been submitted, thank you!</div>

        @endif
@endif
```

But it is showing the success div all the time after first submission. Anyone know where to look for the problem? Thanks!

Comment: Same happens if I do `return redirect()->back()->withInput()` when errors occur - the inputs are in session no matter how many times I refresh and navigate pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out it was about not including `web` middleware in one of the controllers, silly mistake.

The form handler controller had `web` middleware included, so it would set the session, but the controller displaying the form did not have that middleware, so it would not remove the flash data from the session.