# Laravel Session data different in views and controllers

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-blade

In my `PagesController` I have method `view(Page $page)`, which gets called by the route:

`Route::get('{page}', 'PagesController@view');`

The method body is as follows:

```
public function view(Page $page)
{

    // Process content vars
    $page->content = ContentVarsProcessor::process($page->content);

    var_dump(\Session::get('form_contact-form_response'));

    return $page->out();
}
```

And the `$page->out()` body is:

```
public function out()
{

    // ... some processing

    $content = view($view, $data)->render();

    return $content;
}
```

Inside the view, I have

```
{{ var_dump(session('form_'.$form->identifier.'_response')) }}
```

And the interest thing is that the two dumps show different data.. The data is flashed on form validation, and should be gone after 1 request, but it keeps persisting, while in the controller it's showing null. The dumps are as follows:

```
C:\wamp\www\wsv\app\Modules\Pages\Controllers\PagesController.php:21:null

C:\wamp\www\wsv\storage\framework\views\7dbbca5089cdc8f8c9e49cadafb0bb435b7adf4d.php:7:string '{"status":"error","errors":["Name is required"]}' (length=48)
```

On the same page, on the same request. What am I missing here?

Thanks

Comment: Can you check if you have included the facade needed for Session correctly .. or else clear your application data or press shift+f5. Hope any one of the above helps

Comment: In the config facade seems to be defined fine `'Session' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session::class,`, I've cleared my cookies and refreshed page with cache cleared. On form submit, the controller still doesn't seem to get any session data, while in the view session data appears but it persists and can't be deleted.

Comment: Are you sure about dumping the data correctly into the session ? or you are just trying to get it from Session ?

Comment: I've tried returning `redirect()->with(...)` as well as `\Session::set()` and `\Session::put()` before returning. I assume it does put the value in, because it appears in the view, but not the controller.

Comment: Please try using Session::get() and Session::put() for operations. And please check if the data is getting inserted immediately after Session::set('your-key') by using Session::put('your-key'); Please refer to https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/session#retrieving-data for more details

Comment: I seemed to get results same in the controller and the view. However, when I use `Session::flash('key', 'value)` it seems to be persisting the value for all requests indefinitely as if I did `Session::set`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130525/discussion-between-nevermore-and-giedrius).

Answer (score 0):

Same bug as per the other issue - inconsistent middleware included.

[Laravel Flash Data Persisting indefinitely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41121629/laravel-flash-data-persisting-indefinitely)